# Parsing string for further use

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a string like this `"d/\""`. I want to split the string to `\"` using the `split('/')` function. Then I want to format the string as raw string and append it to a list.

When I want to print/write that string of the list I want to get `\"`.

I tried really many approaches. (With replacing \ character, using repr() function, trying to format string as raw string like that `r'%s'%string`)

None of that worked correctly. Maybe someone can help me out getting that desired solution.

Thank you in advance,

Greetings

EDIT: Minimal reproducible example:

JSON Object:

```
  {
    "name": "d/\"",
    "name_encoding": "utf8",
    "value": "/\/\",
  }
```

I want a list with the raw strings like that `['\"', 'utf8', '/\/\']` and when write the list to a file or print it, output should look like that `\", utf8, /\/\`.

Minimal code I use (for reproducing the problem):

```
with open(...) as f:
    for object in ijson.items(f, "item"):
        temp_list =[]
        for attribute_key in object.keys():
            if attribute_key == 'name':
                name_parsed = object[attribute_key].split('/', maxsplit=1)[1]
                temp_list.append(repr(name_parsed)[1:-1])
```

Comment: `"\""` is simply a quotation `"`. The backspace character is not a part of the string. Please show a more specific example of what you have and what you expect to have.

Comment: I read many strings which start with `d/` out of a json file. I want to get the string after the `d/`, so I use `split('/', maxsplit=1)` on the strings. Then I have a problem with escape character though. E.g. strings like `"d/\""` are problematic and dont give me the desired output `\"` I want.

Comment: @asdfyxcvqwer Are the strings elements of the JSON? Could you share some of the data?

Comment: @AMC Yeah the string elements are out of a json file. The for the example corresponding json object looks like this: `"name": "d/\"", "name_encoding": "utf8", "value": "",..`

Comment: @asdfyxcvqwer Can you make a [mcve], so that we can test things?